# Script is not recognized inside my aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this script

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var request;
        function GetDataUsingAJAX() {
            var value = document.getElementById("search").value;
            request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.onreadystatechange = ProcessResponse;
            request.open("GET", "SearchAjax.aspx?searchValue=" + value, true);
            request.send();
        }
        function ProcessResponse() {
            if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = request.responseText;
            }
        }
</script>
```

And this button which should call the script:

```
 <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="GetDataUsingAJAX()" CssClass="btn btn-default" />
```

All of it is in the same page (aspx page).

I keep getting this error :

> Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'ASP.search_aspx' does not contain a
>   definition for 'GetDataUsingAJAX' and no extension method
>   'GetDataUsingAJAX' accepting a first argument of type
>   'ASP.search_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or
>   an assembly reference?)

It can't find `GetDataUsingAJAX()`.

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 3):

`OnClick` is the attribute used to indicate with method in your code-behind file to be executed on the server when the button is clicked.

You're looking for `OnClientClick` which executes javascript in the browser.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ash, I am not getting the Compilation error any more, but for some odd reason it still doesn't get into my function ...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to trigger an AJAX call you don't need to use the Button.

The Button is a WebControl used for submitting the form. You don't want to submit anything, but you want something done locally using AJAX.

In your case you don't have to set the OnClick but the OnClientClick. The OnClientClick for a  normally is there todo something special before submitting. You probably need to return false to actually stop the submit, otherwise your AJAX call won't be processed as expected, since the page is in a new roundtrip itself.
You can stop the submit by making GetDataUsingAJAX() return false.
Then change the call to:

```
OnClientClick="return GetDataUsingAJAX();"
```

An alternative to the Button without any serverside requirements and hence no long clientID and viewstate is a pure hyperlink:

```
<a href="" onclick="return GetDataUsingAJAX();" class="btn btn-default">Search</a>
```

If disabling the submit doesn't solve your issue either, try adding an alert as first line in GetDataUsingAjax() to see whether it actually gets called. If not the script may not be on your page.

Comment: Thanks for replying Dacker, actually it wasn't called due to a typo. fixed that, and its all working now :)

Comment: @Eshel Your welcome. In this case next time you should try to debug what is happening, to see where it stops working. If you can't debug you can still use alerts as mentioned to figure it out.